# Consume emails from G Suite into my personal Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email, pop3

I have enabled Pop3 access on my G Suite Gmail app, and have made sure in the admin panel that Pop3 is allowed. When I go into my personal gmail though and try adding the G Suite pop account, I'm told

> There was a problem connecting to mail.mydomain.us

I'm providing the G Suite email address as the user name, the password, and I'm going against port 110. I've got SSL enabled, but I can't get it to establish the connection between the accounts.

I want all of my email in my personal Gmail, I only use G Suite so I can have a custom domain name with my email address. I don't want to be doing all of my email in G Suite, and everything else in my personal Google account. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue while setting up to retrieval of email from my suite into my Gmail personal account. Called Google support to be able to fix it.

There were 4 things needed:

1. Gmail account/Settings/Forwarding and POP-IMAP/Enable pop for all mail 
   Needs to be turned ON
2. Admin console/Security/Advanced security settings
   Have Less secure apps set as "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps"
3. Admin console/Apps/G Suite/Settings for Gmail/Advanced settings
   Have End user access/Allow per-user outbound gateways ON
4. The POP setup to the G Suite email account needs to use pop.gmail.com, port 995 (instead of the default settings)

Only after doing the 4 steps from above I was able to read the email from my G-suite account.

Answer (score 0):

just get into your GSuite email -> Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP

and under Forwarding select `Forward a copy of incoming mail to mynormaladdr@gmail.com`